# replace any string after specific word using findstr in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I edited this question. What I'm doing now is to replace a string with a string after a specific word or character. What I want is to replace all xml tag `<xml></xml>` with content`SampleValue-(whatever char after the dash)` with `SampleValue-Test`. Below is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
set "file=testinput.xml"
set "getValue=<xml>SampleValue-</xml>"
set "setValue=<xml>SampleValue-Test</xml>"
(
for /f "delims=" %%a IN ('findstr /N "^" %file%') DO (
set "line=%%a"
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "line=!line:%getValue%=%setValue%!"
echo !line:*:=!
endlocal
)
)>tmp
move /Y tmp output.xml
```

Comment: You know, you can enclose the variable=value pair in quotation marks to remove the need for escaping.  Example: `set "getValue=<xml1>SampleValue-.*</xml1>"`.  Then `for /f "tokens=3 delims=-<" %%I in ('findstr /i "%getValue%" textfile') do echo %%I`.  But it's better to parse XML as XML and get the data you need from the DOM.  `powershell "([xml](gc test.xml)).selectSingleNode('//xml1/text()').data -replace 'SampleValue-'"`

Comment: I edited my question. Thanks :)

Comment: Question is what should I do to replace whatever string after the DASH sign with my `setValue` as replacement text

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell is probably the easiest way:

```
@ECHO OFF
set "inFile=testinput.xml"
set "outFile=testoutput.xml"
set "getValue=<xml>SampleValue-</xml>"
set "setValue=<xml>SampleValue-Test</xml>"

powershell -Command "(Get-Content %inFile%) -replace '%getValue%', '%setValue%' | Set-Content %outFile%"
```